# How I Split json.gz file randomly in python?

Tags: python, json, split

I have a large json.gz file, it contain more than million reviews.
I need to spilt it in groups, each group is a json.gz file and must have 200,000 reviews randomly,

how I can do that in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

gzip.GzipFile with json.load and then use random.shuffle and some list slicing and then json.dump with GzipFile again.